# HTML5 footer background color issue

Tags: css, html

I am creating a webpage in HTML5. I was using a basic footer, but the footer's background color didn't extend until the page border. It has a yellow border around it, even though I gave it distinct margins. Can you guys show me how to fix the margins of my footer so that there is no yellow, only white?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>San Joaquin Valley Town Hall</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="../images/favicon.ico">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/c05x_sorkin.css">

<style>

    body {
        background-color: yellow;
        font-size: default;
        border: 10px double blue;
        width: 650px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-bottom: 40px;
        padding-bottom: 0px;



    }

    img {
        float: left;
        margin: 20px;
    }

    main {

        text-align: left;
        background-color: white;
        padding-left: 30px;
        padding-right:30px;
        padding-top: 12px;
        padding-bottom: 0px;


    }

    h1 {
        color: blue;
        font-size: 150%;
    }

    h2 {
        font-size: 125%;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    }

    h3 {
        font-size: 115%;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
    }

    blockquote {
        margin: 0px;
    }

    ul{
        margin-left: 0px;
        padding-left: 20px;
    }

    li {
        margin-left: 0px;
        margin-top: 0px;
    }

    p.citation {
        text-align: right;
        margin-bottom: .75em;
    }

    cite{

        color: blue;
        font-style: normal;
    }

    footer {
        text-align: center;
        border-top: 3.5px solid blue;
        margin-right: 20px;
        margin-left: 20px;
        padding-top: 0px;
        background-color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 90%


    }


</style>

</head>

<body>
<main>

    <h1>Andrew Ross Sorkin, author of <i>Too Big to Fail</i></h1>

    <h3>November 2015</h3>

    <img src="../images/sorkin_desk260.jpg" alt="Andrew Ross Sorkin"    width="260">

    <p>New York Times columnist and author, Andrew Ross Sorkin, has been  described as <q>the most famous financial journalist of his generation.</q> A leading voice on Wall Street and corporate America, his New York Times bestseller, <i>Too Big to Fail</i>, was the first true, behind-the-scenes, moment-by-moment account of how that financial crisis developed into a global tsunami.</p>

    <p>The Economist, The Financial Times, and Business Week all named <i>Too Big To Fail</i> one of the best books of the year. The book was published by Viking October 20, 2009. The book was adapted as a movie by HBO Films and premiered on HBO on May 23, 2011. The film was directed by Curtis Hanson, and the screenplay was written by Peter Gould.</p>

    <h2>Praise for <i>Too Big to Fail</i></h2>

    <blockquote>&ldquo;Vigorously reported, superbly organized...for those of us who didn't pursue MBAs and have the penny-ante salaries to prove it.&rdquo;</blockquote>
    <p class="citation"><cite>Julia Keller, Chicago Tribune</cite></p>

    <blockquote>&ldquo;Sorkin's prodigious reporting and lively writing put the reader in the room for some of the biggest-dollar conference calls in history. It's an entertaining, brisk book.&rdquo;</blockquote>
    <p class= "citation"><cite>Paul M. Barrett, The New York Times Book Review</cite></p>

    <h2>The cast of the movie: <i>Too Big to Fail</i></h2>

    <ul>
        <li>William Hurt as Hank Paulson</li>
        <li>Paul Giamatti as Ben Bernanke</li>
        <li>Billy Crudup as Timothy Geithner</li>
        <li>Edward Asner as Warren Buffet</li>
    </ul>

</main>

<footer>
    <p>Prepared by: Alisha Matreja</p>
    <p>Date: November 8th, 2015</p>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Take away the margins https://jsfiddle.net/8Lfttr01/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are going for this result https://jsfiddle.net/8Lfttr01/

just take the `margin-left` and `margin-right` out of your `.footer` css

Comment: There is still a yellow border on the top and on the bottom of the footer with the blue boundaries though.

Comment: @Timothy ok, I thought you wanted it there. I will update my answer. Give me a minute.

Comment: @Timothy Ok, I fixed the other issues and added them to the top of the css so you can see what I changed https://jsfiddle.net/8Lfttr01/1/

Answer (score 0):

There are really only a couple of lines you need to change in your CSS:

**1. Change:**

```
footer {
text-align: center;
border-top: 3.5px solid blue;
margin-right: 20px;
margin-left: 20px;
padding-top: 0px;
background-color: white;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 90%
}
```

to

```
footer {
text-align: center;
border-top: 3.5px solid blue;
margin: 0 auto;
padding-top: 0px;
background-color: white;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 90%
}
```

**2. Change:**

```
ul {
margin-left: 0px;
padding-left: 20px;
}
```

to

```
ul {
margin: 0;
padding: 0 0 12px 20px;
}
```

**3. Add:**

```
footer p:last-of-type {
margin-bottom: 0;
padding-bottom: 12px;
}
```